# How to make a function that gets me 3 diferent ramdom numbers - Blueprint UE4

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I'm trying to make a simple function that gets me 3 different random integers between 1-10, except one specific integer that will already be randomly generated. Anybody has a good idea? 
I thought about doing with branches but I don't think It will be efficient.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "except one specific integer that will already be randomly generated". If you're just looking to generate some random numbers, there is a RandomInteger function in Blueprints that you can call as many times as needed.

Comment: I´ll give you an example:

First the function will generate a random number between 1 to 10: "7"  ------                       

Then, a second part of the function will generate 3 different integers that could be any number except 7: "2, 6, 4"

Comment: This seems a little bit weird, but i need this function in that way

Comment: If I do just the function randomInteger there is a chance that the numbers generated would not be different

Comment: Are you wanting all 4 numbers to be unique? Or just to ensure the second, third, and fourth numbers aren't the same as the first number? Would the sequence (7, 2, 6, 2) be valid? It would be good to clarify this in your original question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

1. Get a random number (lets say N) with RandomInteger(0, 10)
2. Branch on "is N = 10"?
3. Branch on "is N = 0"?

if one of the above is true, than get the next 3 numbers with range 1-10 or 0-9
else:

1. Get random boolean
2. Branch on random boolean
   3a. Branch true -> get random numbers N1, N2, N3 in range (0, N-1)
   3b. Branch false -> get random numbers N1, N2, N3 in range(N+1, 10)